# Merging Categoricals: How to Handle Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, union, categorical-data

I want to merge the categorical mapping from several series to reassign that merger to these series as their categorical mapping. However
`pd.api.types.union_categoricals` does not merge duplicate elements of Categoricals passed to it. How are you supposed to union Categoricals *whilst* merging duplicates?

Consider this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

ac = pd.Categorical(['a1','a2', 'b1'])
bc = pd.Categorical(['b1','b2', 'a1'])

af = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(ac, dtype="category", name='a'))
bf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(bc, dtype="category", name='b'))

all_categories = pd.api.types.union_categoricals([ac, bc])

print(all_categories)

af.a = af.a.cat.set_categories(all_categories)
bf.b = bf.b.cat.set_categories(all_categories)

df = af.join(bf)
```

For the print-statement I get

```
[a1, a2, b1, b1, b2, a1]
Categories (4, object): [a1, a2, b1, b2]
```

The line `af.a = af.a.cat.set_categories(all_categories)`
 gives me the error  `ValueError: Categorical categories must be unique`.

Ok... then how am I supposed to do this, if the union counterintuitively does not perform an actual set-like union that merges duplicates?

To reiterate: I intend `af.a` and `bf.b` to share the same categorical mapping. For that I first want to merge their mappings and replace the original mappings of the series with the merged mapping. The code does works when `all_categories` is free of duplicates.

Comment: Use `all_categories.categories` with `set_categories`; `union_categoricals` returns a `Categorial` with the set-like union occurring on the _categories_, not the values, which just get concated.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but feels like a workaround and not very elegant:

```
import pandas as pd

ac = pd.Categorical(['a1','a2', 'b1'])
bc = pd.Categorical(['b1','b2', 'a1'])

af = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(ac, dtype="category", name='a'))
bf = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(bc, dtype="category", name='b'))

all_categories = pd.Series(pd.api.types.union_categoricals([ac, bc]))
all_categories.drop_duplicates()

af.a = af.a.cat.set_categories(all_categories.cat.categories)
bf.b = bf.b.cat.set_categories(all_categories.cat.categories)
```